# How to call a method after finish Retrofit call?

Tags: android, retrofit

I use [This library](https://github.com/igalata/Bubble-Picker) to display profiles from API but my problem is `bubblePicker.setAdapter()` get executed before Retrofit call is finished.

I think it's because `enqueue()` is asynchronous method ,so it will executed lines after without waiting.   I have no idea how to solve this problem.

My code will throw NullPointerException because `studentsArray` is null.

Please give some advise. 
Thanks

My Code :

```
public class FriendFragment extends Fragment {

    Http http = new Http();
    final String BASE_URL = http.getUrl();

    String[] studentsArray;
    List < Student > students;

    BubblePicker bubblePicker;


    public static FriendFragment newInstance() {
        FriendFragment fragment = new FriendFragment();
    return fragment;
    }

    private ApiService getInterfaceService() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
        final ApiService mInterfaceService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
        return mInterfaceService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friend, container, false);
        bubblePicker = (BubblePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.picker);
        ApiService mApiService = getInterfaceService();
        Call < GetFriendsPhotoDao > mService = mApiService.photo("2", "2202", "2", "1", "1", "2558");
        //***** Call API Here *****
        mService.enqueue(new Callback < GetFriendsPhotoDao > () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call < GetFriendsPhotoDao > call, Response < GetFriendsPhotoDao > response) {
                GetFriendsPhotoDao getFriendsPhotoDao = response.body();
                if (getFriendsPhotoDao.getSuccess()) {
                    students = getFriendsPhotoDao.getStudent();
                    studentsArray = new String[students.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < studentsArray.length; i++) {
                        studentsArray[i] = students.get(i).getStuId();
                    }
                } 
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call < GetFriendsPhotoDao > call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
        addBubble();
        return rootView;
    }



//***** Add bubbles here *****
private void addBubble() {

    bubblePicker.setBubbleSize(10);
    bubblePicker.setAdapter(new BubblePickerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getTotalCount() {
            return studentsArray.length;
        }

        @NotNull
        @Override
        public PickerItem getItem(int position) {
            PickerItem item = new PickerItem(); item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.person));
            item.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.white));
            return item;
        }
    });
  }

...
}
```

Comment: And why are you not calling it in `onResponse` when that is obviously what gets called after the request is finished?

Comment: Because I got this error `lateinit property items has not been initialized` which is also report on Github [Here](https://github.com/igalata/Bubble-Picker/issues/29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move `addBubble();` from inside `onResponse`, once you have the response

```
mService.enqueue(new Callback < GetFriendsPhotoDao > () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call < GetFriendsPhotoDao > call, Response < GetFriendsPhotoDao > response) {
                GetFriendsPhotoDao getFriendsPhotoDao = response.body();
                if (getFriendsPhotoDao.getSuccess()) {
                    students = getFriendsPhotoDao.getStudent();
                    studentsArray = new String[students.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < studentsArray.length; i++) {
                        studentsArray[i] = students.get(i).getStuId();
                    }
                } 
             addBubble();
             //^^^^^^^
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call < GetFriendsPhotoDao > call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
        //addBubble();
```

Comment: Thanks, Now my array has a value but app crashed because `lateinit property items has not been initialized`  This error's also reported on [Github](https://github.com/igalata/Bubble-Picker/issues/29)

Comment: @mongkonsrisin i am glad that i could help though seems like it is a bug :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are creating an instance of your adapter and set adapter outside of web service override onResponse method that's why data are not set in the adapter.Try this one-

```
    public class FriendFragment extends Fragment {

    Http http = new Http();
    final String BASE_URL = http.getUrl();

    String[] studentsArray;
    List < Student > students;

    BubblePicker bubblePicker;


    public static FriendFragment newInstance() {
        FriendFragment fragment = new FriendFragment();
    return fragment;
    }

    private ApiService getInterfaceService() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
        final ApiService mInterfaceService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
        return mInterfaceService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friend, container, false);
        bubblePicker = (BubblePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.picker);
        ApiService mApiService = getInterfaceService();
        Call < GetFriendsPhotoDao > mService = mApiService.photo("2", "2202", "2", "1", "1", "2558");
        //***** Call API Here *****
        mService.enqueue(new Callback < GetFriendsPhotoDao > () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call < GetFriendsPhotoDao > call, Response < GetFriendsPhotoDao > response) {
                GetFriendsPhotoDao getFriendsPhotoDao = response.body();
                if (getFriendsPhotoDao.getSuccess()) {
                    students = getFriendsPhotoDao.getStudent();
                    studentsArray = new String[students.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < studentsArray.length; i++) {
                        studentsArray[i] = students.get(i).getStuId();
                    }
                    addBubble();
                } 
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call < GetFriendsPhotoDao > call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
        //addBubble();
        return rootView;
    }



//***** Add bubbles here *****
private void addBubble() {

    bubblePicker.setBubbleSize(10);
    bubblePicker.setAdapter(new BubblePickerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getTotalCount() {
            return studentsArray.length;
        }

        @NotNull
        @Override
        public PickerItem getItem(int position) {
            PickerItem item = new PickerItem(); item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.person));
            item.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.white));
            return item;
        }
    });
  }

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this method:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    super.finalize();
    addBubble();     //your func
}
```